# Node Express - Http post to return a file

Tags: node.js, http, express, download

I'm not able to return a file, when submitting a HTTP post

I know that all of my code is functioning, up until the download / sendfile part.

```
var postData = req.body;
var outputString = "";

mkdirp('./server/tmp');

_.each(postData, function (each) {
    outputString += each.variable + ":  " + each.value + " !default;\n";
});

fs.writeFile(path.resolve("./server/tmp/ionic.app.scss"), outputString);

res.attachment(path.resolve("./server/tmp/ionic.app.scss"));
res.end('hello,world\nkeesun,hi', 'UTF-8');
```

How can I make it so that, when the user clicks a button, it sends a POST request, which in turn downloads a file that is created on the fly by the node server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.attachment()` only sets the content disposition header. Use `res.download()` instead.

```
res.download(path.resolve("./server/tmp/ionic.app.scss"));
```

`res.download()` both sets the content disposition header and sends the file.

-- EDIT --

Like I mentioned in my last comment, I failed to mentioned that you should remove the final `res.end()` in your code.

I'm wondering, though, why you're saving the generated text to a file just to send it. A simplified way of doing it would be as follows:

```
var postData = req.body;
var outputString = "";

mkdirp('./server/tmp');

_.each(postData, function (each) {
    outputString += each.variable + ":  " + each.value + " !default;\n";
});


res.attachment("ionic.app.scss");
res.send(outputString);
res.end();
```

This will accomplish the same goal, without having to save the `outputString` to a file first.

Comment: hmm, I've done that now, and I see `Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="ionic.scss"` in my response header, but still no file is being downloaded (no initiation). Any idea why?

Comment: Paolo, I just did a test and it worked for me. The only difference in my code is that I don't have the `res.end()` that you have at the end of your code. I suggest you remove it.

Comment: I've added a working example at [Runnable](http://runnable.com/VBeBCkl1te08g8uN/express-http-post-download-example-for-node-js-and-express-js) for you to checkout.

Comment: Thanks for the example! I realized that I was having an issue with using a HTTP GET + javascript, which is similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery